# How to add up prices delimited by id's of products

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dbo.products where all the products are stored. These products have a unique ID, Name, category and Price.

In a customer database (dbo.customers) the selected orders are pipe separated in one column. For example `"12|61|42|48|56|57"`. Is it possible to get the total price based on what the customer selects? So if 12 is the `ID` of a price 10 product and 61 is a price 8 product the outcome should be 18 when the product column is `"12|61"`?

I've tried to refer to the id of the dbo.prices but I can only select one price at a time.

```
select Price
  from [dbo].[products]
  where id in (12|61|42|48|56|57)
```

So what I expect is the total value of all the selected product, please help.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a single column!  Don't store numbers as strings!

Answer (score 0):

Made third table as orders store customer selected products in that table ,
after that manage foreign key,primary key structure which will identify customer and products data.

then will  get what you want.

use query

sum() for calculating total price etc.

Answer (score 0):

So let's assume that you get your data from some external system, and you are forced to accept that orders will be pipe-delimited garbage.  Let's also assume you don't have the capacity to split this raw data out into a normalised format, storing it in a proper, relational manner.  So in this world you are stuck with a bad data model, and all you can do is query it.

First thing you will need is a way to split out the orders into a usable format.  You could use the built in SPLIT function, but if you don't have access to this because you're on an older version of SQL Server then you could write your own.  Here's an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split] (
    @string VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1))
 RETURNS TABLE
 AS
 RETURN
 (
    WITH Pieces(id, [start], [stop]) AS (
        SELECT 1, 1, CONVERT(INT, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string))
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID + 1, [stop] + 1, CONVERT(INT, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, [stop] + 1)) FROM Pieces WHERE [stop] > 0
    )
    SELECT 
        id,
        SUBSTRING(@string, [start], CASE WHEN [stop] > 0 THEN [stop] - [start] ELSE LEN(@String) END) AS item
    FROM 
        Pieces
 );
```

Once you have that in place you can do things like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.split('12|61|42|48|56|57', '|');
```

Results:

```
id  item
1   12
2   61
3   42
4   48
5   56
6   57
```

Now you can finally construct a query to bring all these parts together.  Here's an example, using table variables, as I had to guess what your schema looks like:

```
DECLARE @customer TABLE (id INT, customer_name VARCHAR(20), [order] VARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @price TABLE (id INT, price INT);
INSERT INTO @customer SELECT 1, 'Fred', '1|2|3';
INSERT INTO @customer SELECT 2, 'Bill', '2|4';
INSERT INTO @customer SELECT 3, 'Mary', '3';
INSERT INTO @price SELECT 1, 5;
INSERT INTO @price SELECT 2, 3;
INSERT INTO @price SELECT 3, 2;
INSERT INTO @price SELECT 4, 1;
SELECT c.id, c.customer_name, COUNT(s.item) AS items_ordered, SUM(p.price) AS total_price FROM @customer c CROSS APPLY dbo.split(c.[order], '|') s INNER JOIN @price p ON p.id = s.item GROUP BY c.id, c.customer_name ORDER BY 1;
```

Results:

```
id  customer_name   items_ordered   total_price
1   Fred    3   10
2   Bill    2   4
3   Mary    1   2
```